# SVN wants to reintegrate on a sync merge

Tags: svn, merge, svn-reintegrate, svn-merge-reintegrate

Some time ago a created a feature branch:

`svn cp ^/trunk ^/branches/feature`

This was done quite a while ago (almost 2 years). The feature branch was put on hold and I now want to recover it. So the first thing I tried was to sync up the work done in the meanwhile.

In my working copy (the branch checkout):

`svn merge ^/trunk`

When I do this it seems to me it's trying to do a reintegrate merge instead of a sync merge:

```
svn: E195016: Reintegrate can only be used if revisions 28502 through 33811 were previously merged from 
svn+ssh://<...>/branches/feature to the reintegrate source, but this is not the case:
trunk/src
  Missing ranges: /branches/feature:28502-28503,28519-28520,28540
trunk/src/app
  Missing ranges: /branches/feature/app:28504-28505,28507,28519,28521-28523,28536,28541-28542
```

The revisions it mentions are the ones made in the branch. I've always done sync merges this way. How can I fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the version of the SVN client and the server?

Comment: Client is 1.9 and server is 1.8.